# Docker nginx can't use http and https at the same time

Tags: docker, nginx

I am using the latest docker nginx. I want to use both http and https to access my website. This is my nginx config so far:

#### default.cnf

```
upstream backends {
    server app:8080;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  example.com;

    # SSL
    # ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/214577452530751.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/214577452530751.key;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE:ECDH:AES:HIGH:!NULL:!aNULL:!MD5:!ADH:!RC4;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    #proxy to webs
    location ~.*/ {
        proxy_redirect off;  
        proxy_set_header Host $host;  
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;  
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;  
        proxy_pass http://backends;
    }
}
```

But When I accessed my server,  just the http is valid. And for the https, nginx will gives a binary logs:

```
nginx         | 120.236.174.140 - - [06/Apr/2018:19:04:40 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xC3\x01\x00\x00\xBF\x03\x03T\xF7v\x15gk\x04\xE2\xC5\xB3\x8B\x10\xAA\xE0\x1C\xA4[\xCE\x01z\xCC\x81\x19\x93\xC6\x11T5\x02\xD7$7\x00\x00\x1CZZ\xC0+\xC0/\xC0,\xC00\xCC\xA9\xCC\xA8\xC0\x13\xC0\x14\x00\x9C\x00\x9D\x00/\x005\x00" 400 174 "-" "-" "-"
```

And the `curl` as follow:

```
kangbb@udo:~$ curl -L  https://example.com
curl: (35) gnutls_handshake() failed: An unexpected TLS packet was received.
```

Where I had written fault? Can anyone give me some adivce? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to seperate them out. There's a bunch of SSL stuff going on with a supposedly HTTP connection. Uncomment `ssl on;` in the one with port 443. Create another server that listens on port 80.

```
upstream backends {
    server app:8080;
}

server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  example.com;

    # SSL
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/214577452530751.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/214577452530751.key;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE:ECDH:AES:HIGH:!NULL:!aNULL:!MD5:!ADH:!RC4;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    #proxy to webs
    location / {
        proxy_redirect off;  
        proxy_set_header Host $host;  
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;  
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;  
        proxy_pass http://backends;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_redirect off;  
        proxy_set_header Host $host;  
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;  
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;  
        proxy_pass http://backends;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more details. What happened when you tried it?

Comment: OK, really thanks for you! What I have done is  modify the `default.conf` as what you have said.  And I have update my questtion, maybe you can get more detail from it.

Comment: I have updated my example. Your locations seem unnecessarily complex. If you want to match all paths, just use a slash by itself.

Answer (score 0):

For docker niginx, it will give you two ports, 80 and 443. If you want to use it for http, bind 80; If you want to use it for https, bind 443.